# Input Fibonacci in table generate PHP

Tags: php, fibonacci

Hello i have the following script to generate a table

```
<?php  error_reporting(null); ?>
<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
Row<br>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['row'] ?>"  name="row"><br/>

Kolom<br>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['kolom'] ?>" name="kolom">
<input type="hidden" name="aksi" value="gen">
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 
if($_POST['aksi']=="gen"){
    echo "<table border=1>";    
        for ($i=1; $i<=$_POST['row']; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
                <?PHP for ($y=1; $y<=$_POST['kolom']; $y++) { ?>
                        <td>Data</td>
                <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    <?php }
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

And i have a script to generate a fibonacci number

```
<?php

$first=0;
$second=1;


echo "$first $second";

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{

  $third = $second + $first;
  echo " $third";


  $first = $second;
  $second = $third;
}

?>
```

I want to join the 2 scripts.

when i a generate a table, Fibonacci needs to be placed inside the table, i don't know how to solve this.

This Result like this

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is it about seleting something from a table? I don't get what you mean by "join 2 script"

Comment: i want when i'm generate table, my fibonanci place in table

Comment: That didn't clarify much. Show us the output your currently getting and what output you're expecting. Remember, we have _no idea_ what you're trying to do and is 100% relying on you to give us a _detailed_ explanation of your issue and expectations.

Comment: He wants to post the numbers in the table in the first code snippet.

Comment: @Andreas but in what form. Should it be just a simple list of fibonacci numbers? What is the second for loop for? Should the numbers be rows or columns?

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Issn't there a `5` missing in the table?

Comment: @Yoshi i think so yes :)

Comment: Is this something someone asked you to do in school or job interview?

Comment: to do in school.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Cannot test so if there are any typos keep them :)

```
<?php  error_reporting(null); ?>
<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
Row<br>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['row'] ?>"  name="row"><br/>

Kolom<br>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['kolom'] ?>" name="kolom">
<input type="hidden" name="aksi" value="gen">
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 
if($_POST['aksi']=="gen"){

  $first=0;
  $second=1;
?>    
<table border=1>
<?php
  for ($i=0; $i<$_POST['row']; $i++) {
?>
  <tr>
<?PHP 
    for ($y=0; $y<$_POST['kolom']; $y++) {

      /* first two should be 0 and 1*/
      if($y < 2 && $i == 0) {
?>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
<?php 
        $y += 2;
      } else {

        $third = $second + $first;
?>
    <td><?php echo($third); ?></td>
<?php 

        $first = $second;
        $second = $third;
      }
    }
?>
  </tr>
<?php
  }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: @Gotech not fibonanncy what? Explain further please.